# Winforms WebBrowser-Controls can't load HTML

Tags: winforms, youtube, webbrowser-control

I have HTML code for YouTube player. If I open the .html file in IE, YouTube player loads successfully, but if I use WebBrowser control to load HTML text. Nothing happens in Webbrowser, it just blanks, I have no idea why WebBrowser can't load.

```
var html = File.ReadAllText(@"Lala.html");
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(false);
    webBrowser1.Document.Write(html);
}
webBrowser1.Refresh();
```

and the HTML code is

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>    
    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {        
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: 'wUypYRJVA90',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          },
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1
          }
        });
    }

    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
        if(event.data === 0) {            
            alert('done');
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've never tried to control a browser this way, so not an expert, but your first snippet begs the question, if your app doesn't work, how can you debug when you are suppressing errors?

Comment: Please can you add more of your C# so that we can see how you've set up and defined your WebBrowser object, thanks!

Comment: ScriptErrorsSuppressed is just for skipping the script warning at the beginning. We can turn it on, choose yes for popup dialog. The behaviors are same.

Comment: There is no other setup. I just drag and drop the webbrowser control on form and add the code above.